# error installing caldecott

Tags: mysql, database, jakarta-ee, cloud-foundry, vmc

recently i made web application and want to atatch my database with it ..though i followed steps of doing it but still i am getting error ..i dont know where's problem i did in steps .. please let me know where i am wrong

[image: first image while installing caldecott]

[image: second image while installing caldecott]

[image: third image while installing caldecott]

please help me where i am wrong or what i skipped ..
thankyou..

Answer (score 2):

I had problems install caldecott , i got the

```
ERROR:  Error installing caldecott:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

error :

i found this resource  : http://www.clausconrad.com/blog/installing-caldecott-on-windows

which was helpfull but my problem was **i had multiple ruby installations on my system !**

so make sure you are using the right ruby installation and delete the others if needed :
i had :

C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe

and

C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe

i deleted the first one and everything went fine , be sure to install the devkit like the link says , and everything should be allright.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue installing eventmachine on Windows. Try this instead:

```
gem install eventmachine --pre
gem install caldecott
```

Comment: can u help me by telling steps of how to attatch my database (.sql) file with my application..
i uploaded my application with `vmc push` 
then created service `vmc create-service`
it created mysql-13ec 
then i used command `vmc tunnel mysql-13ec`
i as per instruction it asked for client out  of 1) none
2) mysql 3)mysqldump 
when i did 3) mysqldump
it says mysql dump is not recognized as internal or external command
and ERROR : mysqldump execution failed 
; is it your $PATH ?  ..............
Please help me over this how to attatch my database from system to my application ..

Comment: The error is stating it can't find the mysqldump program in the Windows path environment variable. Can you run `mysqldump` from your command prompt, or do you have to specify the full path to the executable? See here for instructions on modifying the path variable: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

To install Caldecott requires Ruby 1.9.2.
Check version by

```
ruby -v
```

if not 1.9
update the version and re try to install

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that you installed `C compiler` in your local computer...
if you are using Linux you can run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

if you are in windows you will have find a C compiler from the net.
After installing this C compiler, you can now run

```
 sudo gem install caldecott
```

If this is not working, try

```
ruby -v
```

to see if the version is 1.9.3 or above....

then repeat

hope that helps