# Issue installing caldecott, make inoperable command

Tags: ruby, database, windows-7, rubygems, devkit

I've been trying to install this for a few days now with no success. Looking for help, I've been through this site a half dozen times to try and resolve the issue but I'm not having any luck.

```
c:\Ruby193\DevKit>gem install caldecott --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing caldecott:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/escape_ut
ils-0.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/escape_utils-0.3.2/ext/esc
ape_utils/gem_make.out
```

I've attempted to follow the instructions on this post
-[Make Is Not Recognized as an internal or exernal command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157068/make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-qt-sdk-windows)

By Doing this:

```
c:\Ruby193>set make=mingw32-make
```

I unfortunately still get:

```
c:\Ruby193>gem install caldecott --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing caldecott:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

mingw32-make
'mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/escape_ut
ils-0.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/escape_utils-0.3.2/ext/esc
ape_utils/gem_make.out
```

I've also done:

```
c:\Ruby193\DevKit>gem install eventmachine --pre
```

As discussed here.
-[Error Installing Caldecott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740541/error-installing-caldecott)

HALP!!! What am I doing wrong?

Windows 7
Running CMD as Admin
Ruby v1.9.3
DevKit - installed, in Ruby Folder, and postinstall ran

---

***Update:***

I've attempted to create my own match.bat file in the c:/ruby193/devkit/mingw/bin that should forward the make command to mingw32-make, still successful but here is my code for the batch (match.bat) file.

```
@echo off
mingw32-make %*
```

As explained on this forum.
-[make.bat](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8475)

Still no luck, I'll likely continue to roll my face on the keyboard until I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to install without `platform` arugment, simply this command

```
$ gem install caldecott
```

what error you get now?

Comment: Installing native gems on windows is always a pain. so, maybe it you can try to spin-up Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox. On Linux, install native gems is quite easy & well supported.

Comment: I might try that some time. I've been wanting to build a new desktop and have Windows and Ubuntu bootable. Just haven't had the cash money to build what I want. If I don't have any results by the end of tonight I suppose I'll have to result to VitrualBox. 

Cheers none the less.